# Vue v-for loop 'item' is Undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having an issue where "item" is being returned as undefined when trying to loop over the contents and display it in my HTML. Any help is greatly appreciated.

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'item' is undefined

**HTML**

```
<template id="home">
    <div>
        <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary">Test</b-button>
        <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
          <b-card>
            <p class="card-text" v-for="item in records">
                {{ item.model }}
            </p>
          </b-card>
        </b-collapse>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const home = {
    template: '#home',
    data: function () {
        return {
            records: [],
            loading: true
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.loadRecords();
    },
    computed: {
    },
    methods: {
        async loadRecords() {
            this.loading = true;

            try {
                await axios.request({
                    url: 'load_records',
                    method: 'GET'
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.records = JSON.stringify(response.data['records']);
                    console.log(this.records);
                })
            } catch (err) {
                alert("Could not get the list of devices\n" + err);
            }
        },
    }
}
```

```
console.log(this.records);

[{"aaa_binding":"F","aaa_connection":"T","aaa_console":"T","aaa_network":"T","aaa_system":"F","aaa_vty":"T","banner":"T","exec_timeout_console":"F","exec_timeout_ssh":"T","finger_service":"T","hostname":"test1","id":615,"logging_buffer":"T","logging_remote":"T","logging_timestamp":"T","loopback":"T","model":"Test-model1","ntp":"T","ntp_binding":"T","remote_startup_config":"T","snmp":"F","vendor":"Cisco"},{"aaa_binding":"F","aaa_connection":"T","aaa_console":"T","aaa_network":"T","aaa_system":"F","aaa_vty":"T","banner":"T","exec_timeout_console":"F","exec_timeout_ssh":"T","finger_service":"T","hostname":"Test2","id":892,"logging_buffer":"T","logging_remote":"T","logging_timestamp":"T","loopback":"T","model":"Test-Model2","ntp":"T","ntp_binding":"T","remote_startup_config":"T","snmp":"F","vendor":"Cisco"}]
```

Comment: Why are you stringifying the objects? It should be `this.records = response.data.records;` not `this.records = JSON.stringify(response.data['records']);`

Comment: if the data returned as string in this case you have to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Changing it to response.data.records yields the same results. item is undefined.

Comment: are you using `x-template` syntax?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim you saved me! I had to add {% raw %} {% endraw %} tags within my template.

Comment: which backend framework are you using?

Comment: It's a VueJS / Flask application

Answer (score 0):

I will recommended one advice, add v-bind:key="" to the directive v-for:

```
<p class="card-text" v-for="(item, index) in records" v-bind:key="index">
  {{ item.model }}
</p>
```

In addittion, make sure that records array has 'model' property.

Change this code:

```
this.records = JSON.stringify(response.data['records']);
```

to:

```
this.records = response.data.records;
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` method is converting Object(JSON) type to String type.

So after call API, this.record's data type is String

You need to change code;

```
this.records = response.data.records
```